# Make a new column (migration) between two other columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-migrations

Is there a quick/easy way to make a migration that adds a new column between two existing columns?

Note: I googled and couldn't find an obvious answer. But I also am curious if it's even good practice (since if for some reason other column/s were removed, then the migration may fail?)

Comment: What do you mean by `between`?

Comment: For a user, say I had a table with some columns, then cols `facebook`, `twitch`, `instagram` ... then other cols... Then later I remembered I should add `linkedin` column, but would prefer it to exist next to the similar columns. So say in this case between twitch and instagram

Comment: Rails does not support this in migrations, since changing column ordering isn't supported by all database engines (and also, Rails' philosophy dictates you never think too hard about your database internals...). There are ways to do it, like copying all data into a new table with the right ordering, though if your app hasn't hit prod yet you can just edit schema.rb or structure.sql directly.

Comment: @RobertNubel that makes sense. And explains why I had trouble finding it. To discover 'nope, can't do that' is as good as any other, as it saves further searching

Comment: Migrations are really just a DSL to create SQL strings and run them in a repeatable way across environments. If you can't generate the SQL you want with the DSL you can always use `execute` to execute a raw DSL string. So the answer to this question is really just to google the database name and `change column order`. On some DBs its possible. Others not.

Comment: If you haven't commited your changes to production you can also reorder migrations by rolling them back and then changing the timestamps in the file name.

Comment: Why is it so important for you?

Comment: @MaciekR purely to keep things organised. Say a table has 30 columns, and 5 are 'similar' then it makes sense to keep them nearby. Example: if I near feature is added in the future that uses those columns, the developer has less chance of errantly forgetting one if they're kept together, but greater chance if they're spread out and the dev doesn't necessarily know to go and look for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't commited your changes to production you can reorder migrations by rolling them back and then changing the timestamps in the file name.

If thats not an alternative you can actually re-order the columns on some databases directly with SQL even if its not part of the migrations DSL. Migrations are after all really just a DSL to create SQL strings and run them in a repeatable way across environments.

If you can't generate the SQL you want with the DSL you can always use `execute` to execute a raw DSL string.

```
# MySQL example
class ReorderYourTableName  < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    execute "alter table yourTableName change column yourColumnName yourColumnName dataType after yourSpecificColumnName;"
  end
end
```

However on some DBs you can't actually reorder the columns without extensive steps of creating new columns and shuffling the data around.